# php gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); Failure

Tags: php

I currently have a script with the following code below. I have 50 users using this code. Now essentially this code returns the host name on the client computer which is the right answer. Now recently on two of these machines it's returning the ip address which is not what I want. Why is this code returning the ip address as opposed to the host name.

Having looked in the php manual for this function. it says I quote

"Returns the host name on success, the unmodified ip_address on failure, or FALSE on malformed input."

Because the function is failing the ip address is returned. Why would this function be failing on two machines? It returns the host name on the other 48 machines as expected.

Any guidance or help much appreciated.

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname;
?>
```

Comment: host names are set on those two machines?

Comment: can the hostname tor those 2 machines be resolved? try a `nslookup` for those hosts

Comment: Is this running on the local network? Do the machines still exist on the same subnets? Do they respond to ping via cmdline? Could there have been changes to their firewall settings?

Comment: Yes our computers are on a domain. how do I check to see if the host names are set?